# Clustering 3D with survey data

Tags: python, clustering, rstudio, 3d-reconstruction

I have data obtained from a survey and I would like to perform a 3D clustering of the individuals who have answered the survey based on 3 of the questions they have answered:

- Are you satisfied with product x? The range of responses is: strongly agree, agree, neutral, not satisfied, not satisfied at all.
- Would you buy product x again? the range of answers is: strongly agree, agree, neutral, disagree, do not agree, not at all agree
- How much would you recommend product x to your family, friends... (range from 0 to 10)?

The thing is that I am not sure how to start, do you think I should first convert the answers of the first two questions to numbers (for example: strongly agree : 1)? I also have doubts about the libraries that allow me to do this.

The result I would like to get would be something like the example graphical representation you can see on the following page, rotated and showing the clusters found: https://projector.tensorflow.org/

Answer (score 1):

Convert your categorical choices into a range of 0 to 1. Convert your 1-10 scale to 0-1. Throw [sklearn k-means](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) at it. Use the [elbow method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/elbow-method-for-optimal-value-of-k-in-kmeans/) for deciding how many clusters there are.

For plotting the clusters, [plotly 3d scatterplot](https://plotly.com/python/3d-scatter-plots/) will get you up and running (with separate colors for each cluster) very quickly.  I question if this is the right technique tho ... you will have points on top of each-other. You could jitter the points(add noise in each direction) or use the opacity of the color to designate how many points belong at that point.